# A differential equation with homogeneous coefficients: $(x+y) dx - (x-y) dy = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have a differential equation with homogeneous coefficient:

$$ (x+y) dx - (x-y) dy = 0  $$

Functions $ P(x) = x+y$ and $ Q(x) = - x-y  $ are both homoegeneous functions of order 1. So I can use substitusion:

$$ y = ux, dy = udx + xdu $$

(because it will lead to a differential equation in which the variables are separable)

So after this substitution I'm obtaining result:

$$ (u+ux)dx - (x-ux)(udx + xdu) = 0 $$

After simplification I have:

$$ x^{2} (u-1)du + x(1+u^{2})dx = 0  $$

Now I'm dividing both sides by $x^{2} \cdot (1+u^{2})$ and I'm obtaining:

$$  \frac{u-1}{1+u^{2}}du + \frac{dx}{x} = 0 $$

Next, because:

$$ \int \frac{u-1}{1+u^{2}}du = \frac{1}{2} \ln|u^{2} +1 | - \arctan(u) +C  $$

and:

$$ \int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln| x| + C$$

I have a solution:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \ln| u^{2} + 1| - \arctan(u) + \ln|x| = C$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} \ln|\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}} +1| - \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) + \ln|x| = C   $$

After simplification, I can obtain result:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \ln( x^{2} + y^{2})  - \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) = C $$

In book from this exercise from there is a little diffrent answer :

$$  \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2 + y^2) = C $$

Is my solution incorrect? I will be grateful for an explanation

Comment: You mean doesn't have a modulus? Well observe that $x^2 + y^2$ is always greater or equals to 0 so the modulus is redundant.

Comment: OK, you are right! Thanks

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: This type of ODE may also have singular solution9s) which are oftemn not looked for. you may  see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219211/can-a-first-order-homogeneous-ode-have-singular-solutions-free-of-a-constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions are correct. Note that $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Therefore, one may define $C=-k$ on your solution:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)-\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=-k$$
Multiplying both sides by $-1$, we obtain the same solution the book obtained:
$$\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)=k$$

Comment: Ok you've written right. I thought that I had made a mistake with sing in some place.