# Solving a homogenous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I am taking a course on differential equations. In my study booklet, I am given the following problem:

> Solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x+y}{3x+2y}$$

**My solution.**

$(2x + y)dx - (3x+2y)dy = 0$

This differential equation is not separable. Substituting $y=ux$, $dy=u dx + x du$, we obtain :

$P(x,ux)=2x+ux=x(2+u)$

$Q(x,ux)=3x+2ux=x(3+2u)$

If $x\neq 0$, we have :

$\begin{align}
(2 + u)dx &- (3 + 2u)dy &= 0 \\
(2 + u)dx &- (3 + 2u)(udx+ xdu) &= 0\\
(2 + u)dx &- (3u + 2u^2)dx - (3 + 2u)xdu &=0\\
(2 - 2u - 2u^2)dx &- (3+2u)xdu &= 0\\
\frac{dx}{x} &- \frac{3+2u}{2 - 2u - 2u^2}du &= 0
\end{align}$

This differential equation is now in the separable form. It's solution is :

$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x} &- \int\frac{3+2u}{2 - 2u - 2u^2}du &= c
\end{align}
$

Further,

$
\begin{align}
(2 - 2u - 2u^2)'&= 2(1 - u - u^2)' \\
                &= 2(-1 - 2u) \\
                &= -2 - 4u \\
\end{align}
$

$\boxed {\therefore  (3 + 2u) = -\frac{1}{2}(-2 - 4u) + 2}$

And,

$
\begin{align}
(2 - 2u - 2u^2) &= -2(u^2 + u - 1) \\
                &= -2\{(u+1/2)^2-5/4\} \\
                &= -2\{(u+1/2)^2-(\sqrt 5/2)^2\} \\
                &= 2\{(\sqrt 5/2)^2-(u+1/2)^2\} \\
\end{align}
$

$\boxed {(2 - 2u - 2u^2) = 2\{(\sqrt 5/2)^2-(u+1/2)^2\}}$

Making these substitutions into the integral, we obtain :

$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x} &- \int\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})(-2-4u)}{2 - 2u - 2u^2}du &- \int\frac{2}{2\{(\sqrt 5/2)^2-(u+1/2)^2\}}du &= c \\
\log x &+ \frac{1}{2} \log (2 - 2u - 2u^2) &- \frac{1}{2(\sqrt {5}/2)}\log \left({\frac{u+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}}{u+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}}}\right) &= c \\ 
& \log (2x^2 - 2xy - 2y^2) & - \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} \log \left(\frac{2y + x(1 - \sqrt 5)}{2y + x(1 + \sqrt 5)}\right) &= c
\end{align}
$

However, my solution doesn't match with what's given in the book. Could someone please verify my steps?

Comment: It seems correct. what's your book's answer?

Comment: $(y^2+xy-x^2) \cdot \frac{2y + (1 - \sqrt 5)x}{2y + (1 + \sqrt 5)x}$. I think it might be a typo. The irrational $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ outside the log, should have been present atleast as a power, or so I think.

Comment: Yes, $1/\sqrt5$ is necessary behind of the log and isn't negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$y(x)=v(x)x$$ then we get
$$\frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}(v(x)+3)}{-v(x)^2-2v(x)+2}=\frac{1}{x}$$
and integrate.
The solution should be $$\text{Solve}\left[\frac{1}{5} \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right) \log \left(-\frac{2
   y(x)}{x}+\sqrt{5}-1\right)+\frac{1}{5} \left(5-2 \sqrt{5}\right) \log \left(\frac{2
   y(x)}{x}+\sqrt{5}+1\right)=c_1-2 \log (x),y(x)\right]$$

Comment: Did you read the question? What you propose as hint is exactly what was done.

Answer (score 1):

The solution and method given by Dr. SG should be correct which has one constant of integration $c$ and rightly so, you get the general solution of your ODE.  But, I want to bring your attention to the fact that in your ODE if you put $y=vx$ but treat $v$ as contant, you get two roost of $v$ as $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$. So your ODE has two singular (fixed or essential) solutions without any constant of integration which are $y=v_1x$ and $y=v_2x$. These singular solutions are  often not looked for. 
[Can a first order homogeneous ODE have singular solution(s) (free of a constant)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219211/can-a-first-order-homogeneous-ode-have-singular-solutions-free-of-a-constant)