# solving a differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4xy − x^2 + y^2}{ 4x^2}, \qquad y(1) = 2$, which method should I use.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE but when I tried using the exact method , my $F(x,y)$ and  $F(y,x)$ are not equal hence I'm stuck

> $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4xy − x^2 + y^2}{  4x^2}  \qquad   \text{  given the boundary} \qquad y(1) = 2$$

Comment: Please use Latex to format your equations and show us what you have tried by editing your question to include your work (in Latex).

Comment: Exactly where are you stuck? You obviously did some integration to get $F$. Why is it important that $F(x,y)=F(y,x)$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{y^2}{4x^2} \quad (1)$$

Let $\frac{y}{x} = v$.

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{dv}{dx} + v$$

Now $(1)$ becomes,

$$x\frac{dv}{dx} + v = v - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{v^2}{4}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yesss thank you very very much

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Plz also mark the answer as accepted by clicking the $\checkmark$ button.

Answer (score 0):

In these homogeneous ODE, on does not look for the singular solution(s). For this you assume $v$ to be a constant and put $y=vx$ in the ODE. You get $v^2=1$. So $y=\pm x$ are the singular solutions withour a constant of integration. Check that apart from the solution of Vizag, these two also satisfy the ODE. YTou may see:

[Can a first order homogeneous ODE have singular solution(s) (free of a constant)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219211/can-a-first-order-homogeneous-ode-have-singular-solutions-free-of-a-constant)