# Differential equation substitution f(x/t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Hello I have the differential equation $$x'=\frac{8t+10x}{17t+x}$$
Brought it in a eqation where I can substitute $$ u=\frac{x}{t}$$
and after some transformations I got the equation 
$$ \frac{17+u}{8-7u-u^2}du=\frac{1}{t}dt $$
with the following equation
$$ -2ln(u-1)+ln(u+8)=ln(t)+c$$
Then I tried to multiply it with $$e$$ to make the $$ln()$$ disappear 
then I got the equation $$ \frac{u+8}{(u-1)^2}=te^c$$ but now I dont know how to resubstitute or to break the fracture.Thanks,Ciwan.

Comment: If you have $ -2ln(u-1)+ln(u+8)=ln(t)+c$, then $e^{-2ln(u-1)+ln(u+8)}=e^{ln(t)+c}$, that is, $\frac{u-8}{(u-1)^2}=K\,t$

Answer (score 1):

$$-2ln(u-1)+ln(u+8)=ln(t)+c \implies  \frac {u+8}{(u-1)^2} =ct $$

Go from there with $$u=x/t$$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have solved it. But usually,one does not look for singular solution(s)  of such an ODE. Put $u=x/t$ in the ODE but treat $u$ as constant to get $u^2+7u-8=0$ and $u=-8,1$. So $x=-8t$ and $t$ are the singular solutions of thisODEe which are without any constant of integration. These two are additional solutions apart from the one obtained by the proposer which is the general  solution with a constant $c$. You may see:

[Can a first order homogeneous ODE have singular solution(s) (free of a constant)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219211/can-a-first-order-homogeneous-ode-have-singular-solutions-free-of-a-constant)

Comment: This answer should be modified. OP didn't solve it correctly. In the answer, the exponential map $x \mapsto e^x$ is treated as linear, which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont know what you mean in general, do you mean I should not integrate or what?

Comment: Last equation sould be read as $ (u+8)* \frac{1}{(u-1)^2}=t*e^c$

Comment: Thanks @popi but how do I get the form of u=....

Comment: $u(t)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+36 K \,t}}{2K\,t}+1$ ($K$ is your $e^c$) and then $x(t)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+36 K \,t}}{2K}+t$

Comment: $x= - 8t, t$ are two additional solutions. Apart from the one you got in your solution.

Comment: thanks @popi can you please show me how did you get there ?

Comment: Calling $u-1=z$ you have $\frac{z+9}{z^2}=K\,t$ or $K\,t\,z^2-z-9=0$. Solving this equation you obtain the solution